# Powerapps, Button with If condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to make my arrow button have the following logic, If `Status = Submitted`, do not go into the edit screen.

I pretty much want to lock the record if Status is submitted.

I tried the below and it doesn't work.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any error? What is the data type of "Status" column, choice or single line of text? Is your "edit screen" & `BrowseScreen1` same?

Comment: No error, `Status` in ms list is actually a "single line of text" .  Edit screen and Browse screen are 2 separate screens.

Comment: In your formula, you are not redirecting user to edit screen when status is submitted instead you are redirecting to browse screen. Then what is the problem with your formula here?

Comment: the formula is directing to edit screen, it should be staying on the same screen if `Status=Submitted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Status column is of type "Single line of text", try using formula like:

```
If(ThisItem.Status = "Submitted", Navigate(BrowseScreen1, None), Navigate(EditScreen1, None))
```

This formula will redirect user to `BrowseScreen1` when `Status="Submitted"` else it will redirect user to `EditScreen1`.

---

If you want user to stay on same screen when `Status="Submitted"`, use this:

```
If(ThisItem.Status = "Submitted", false, Navigate(EditScreen1, None))
```

Comment: why do you use `<>` over `=` , it doesn't seem to work with either.

Comment: `<>` is for "Not equal to" operations. you can use either one based on your conditions.

Comment: ah okay got it, I think my "Select(Parent)" was throwing off the functionality. Your formula works!